# Does this question make sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

I currently have a question in a Quantum Mechanics course, which doesn't seem like it makes sense to solve. I obviously am not looking for a solution, but I want to check if it is even possible with the given information before wrecking my head any further. The question is as follows:

> $\text{By evaluation of } \langle E \rangle \text{ and } \langle E \rangle ^2 \text{ for a free particle, verify Einstein's postulate, } E = \hbar \omega$.

The wavefunction we have used for a free particle in this course is a stanard plane wave $Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$, but this is not normalisable and thus cannot be used to find the expectation value of the energy. I have thought that this could be solved by taking a wave packet, or by using fourier analysis, but to my knowledge both of these methods require further information than just a free particle.

So my basic question is is does this question work in the first place, or will I have to assume a gaussian wave packet etc.

Comment: Hint: use the time-DEPENDENT Schroedinger equation on the above wavefunction. What do you get? What do you infer?

Comment: I was thinking this, but I wasn’t sure if this gave the expectation value of the energy, or just the energy as a function of k. I also in this case am not sure of the significance of finding the square of the expectation value, although not sure of that to begin with.